# How to sum a column based on existance of value in another column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, spreadsheet, microsoft-excel-2019

I have the following sheet:

[image]

I want a sum of individual spending by Frank, John and Nancy in the yellow cells.  Each person's spending is denoted by an `x`.  I tried the `SUMIF` formula, but I don't know how to denote criteria to be the existence of a value in the cell.

Or perhaps I am simply using the wrong formula for this type of task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Syntax for SUMIF, according to the relevant [microsoft support article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumif-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b):

```
SUMIF(range, criteria, [sum_range])
```

> For example, the formula =SUMIF(B2:B5, "John", C2:C5) sums only the values in the range C2:C5, where the corresponding cells in the range B2:B5 equal "John."

In your case that would be

```
=SUMIF(G2:G15, "x", D2:D15)
```